# How to handle File Upload by Appweb with Ejscript

Tags: web-services, file-upload, upload, serverside-javascript, ejs

My web apps was deployed on embedded linux, and I used AppWeb as a webserver.
I used Appweb 3.3.2, with Ejscript 1.1.2

And now, I want to upload a file by web browser to server. In Ejscript's document (http://www.ejscript.org/products/ejs/doc-1/api/ejscript/index.html), I can use Request.files to get a buffer of file uploaded.

But when I uses Request.files, it had an error object NULL

There is my simple page upload html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Time Attendance Web Control</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upFile.ejs">
            Database to upload: <input type="file" name="upfile">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And ejscript page to handle: **upFile.ejs**

```
<%
    var rq = new Request();
    write(rq.files['upfile'].size);  // I just write simple code to debug
%>
```

And this is error I got:

```
Error rendering: "upFile.ejs".

Object reference is null
Stack:
 [00] upFile.es, _Solo_upFileView.render, line 10 -> write(rq.files['upfile'].size);  // I just write simple code to debug
 [01] script, Controller.renderView, line 0
```

Anybody help me, plz...
And who can give me an example ejscript page to save file upload to server...

Thanks,

Tidus Le

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be creating your own Request object. That is created for you and accessible in the "request" variable.

You can do:

write(request.files.upfile.size)

I'd also recommend you upgrade to Appweb 4 and Ejscript 2. Much more flexible.

Comment: When I did my project, Appweb 4 and Ejs 2 is not stable. So I chose the stable version ^^. Thanks for your recommend